# Preposition- Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives

Jack is better .... English, but he is worse ... Math than I am.

Which preposition is suitable? 
a) at/ in 
b) in/ at
c) at/ at
d) in/ in

I just know "good at" and "weak in". I'm confusing to choose the answer. When you use comparative, which preposition is more suitable? What is the correct answer?

Comment: to be good at something, to be bad at something.

Answer (score 1):

Both "at" and "in" are acceptable, although in the context of describing someone's *skill*, "at" sounds better to me.

> He is worse **at** Math than I am.

Still, "in" is common:

> He is weak **in** Math, but good **in** English.

"Weak at" is perfectly fine:

> The entire team is **weak at** shooting free throws.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer: c) at/at**

In general, Math and English are both subjects/topics. However, in this context,

> **better** ____  English
>
> **worse** ____  Math

we are referring to how good/bad the person is at performing tasks related to the respective subjects.

One can only good/bad *at* something, **NOT** *in* it.